# Why has $p(\lambda)$ exactly one positive zero?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

Let $p(\lambda ) = {a_m}{\lambda ^m} + {a_{m - 1}}{\lambda ^{m - 1}} +  \cdots  + {a_1}\lambda  - {a_0}$ and ${a_0} > 0,{a_1},{a_2}, \ldots ,{a_m} \ge 0$, and at least one of the coefficients ${a_1},{a_2}, \ldots ,{a_m}$ positive.

Why has $p(\lambda)$ exactly one positive zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$p^{'} (\lambda )$ for $\lambda>0$ is positive since you've lost the $a_0$. It's value at $\lambda=0$ is $-a_0$ which is negative. It can only go up from there.

Answer (score 2):

Equation

$$p(\lambda ) = {a_m}{\lambda ^m} + {a_{m - 1}}{\lambda ^{m - 1}} +  \cdots  + {a_1}\lambda  - {a_0}=0$$

can be considered as the equation verified by the abscissas of the intersection points of

$$\begin{cases}y&=&f(\lambda)\\
y&=&a_0\end{cases} \ \ \text{with} \ \ f(\lambda):={a_m}{\lambda ^m} + {a_{m - 1}}{\lambda ^{m - 1}} +  \cdots  + {a_1}\lambda$$

The first equation is that of a curve passing through the origin $f(0)=0$ and such that $lim_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty}(f(\lambda))=+\infty$. This curve intersects necessarily at least once the horizontal line with equation $y=a_0$.